# Simplify importing for my library at pip

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a library:

```
my_library
  - my_library
    - __init__.py
    - main.py
    - file2.py
    - file3.py
```

In main.py I have this:

```
  class MyMainClass....
```

That library is submitted to pip. When I install it from pip and import it, I have to do it like this:

```
from my_library.main import MyMainClass
```

Is there any to change it (since its mine) so I (and others) can import it like this:

```
from my_library import MyMainClass
```

I figure it has to do with `__init__.py` but how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to import the class within `__init__.py`.

```
from .main import MyMainClass
```

That exposes it directly in `my_library` so your import will work.

Comment: for some reason it gives me an error "no module named main"

Comment: you've forgotten the dot.